# n-globular sets and n-categories

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Is the forgetfull functor between the category of n-categories and the category of n-globular sets always monadic?

It's seems so, but, in nLab, they are talking only about "2-globular sets and 2-categories". I wonder if I was missing something...

And how about n-computads for strict n-categories? Are n-categories always monadic over the n-computads?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Unless you are talking about strict $n$-categories, there are simply too many different definitions of $n$-categories for your question to make sense.

Comment: I was talking about strict n-categories. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: If this is true it should be somewhere in Leinster (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049).

Comment: @Qiaochu I've never seen that book before - thanks for the link! The book seems interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article *Strict $\omega$-categories are monadic over polygraphs* [Mé16](http://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00139) by F. Métayer answers positively to the (non-strict!) monadicity of the category $n\text{-}\mathbf{Cat}$ of  $n$-categories over the category $n\text{-}\mathbf{Pol}$ of $n$-computads (aka $n$-polygraphs).

The strict monadicity of $n$-categories over the category $n\text{-}\mathbf{Glob}$ of $n$-globular sets is easier and references for very general monadicity theorems which apply for presheaves categories, such as $n\text{-}\mathbf{Glob}$ and unlike $n\text{-}\mathbf{Pol}$, can be found in [Mé16](http://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00139), as well.